# Creating tasks for task scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-10, entra-id, task-scheduler, microsoft-intune

We use Azure-AD with Intune at work and I was wondering if it is possible to utilise it to set task scheduler tasks. Checking the CSP library did not prove helpful.

I know I can utilise power-shell scripts to achieve all we need and more, but setting task scheduler would feel more native and avoid some of the issues we have encountered using power-shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run scheduled tasks, there is no way with Intune. Indeed use the task scheduler. You need to deploy an application/MSI that creates the scheduled task. That's at least how we do it.